# how do i assign different variables to text in one line in java?

Tags: java, variables, vector, text-files, readfile

i'm making a program on java to read from a text file and i have already read it but i'm having trouble assigning variables to each data. Here's what i have.

```
try{
   BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("//File here//"));
   while((lineContents=br.readLine())!=null){
   Parts = (lineContents.split(";"));
   lineArray.add(lineContents);
   counter++;

// for example 

 System.out.println( Parts[0]); 
 System.out.println( Parts[1]);   
 System.out.println( Parts[2]);   
 System.out.println( Parts[3]);   
   }

 }
 catch(FileNotFoundException fne){
 fne.printStackTrace();
 }
 catch(IOException io){
 io.printStackTrace();
 }

 }}
```

the text file looks like this

```
 person1;work1;1111;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
 person2;work2;2222;1,3,2,4,5,2,3,4,1,3
 person3;work3;3333;4,5,3,7,2,3,4,2,1,5
```

what the console prints out looks like this

```
person1
work1
1111
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
person2
work2
2222
1,3,2,4,5,2,3,4,1,3
person3
work3
3333
4,5,3,7,2,3,4,2,1,5
```

i'm going to put it in a GUI so don't worry about the console. I want to appoint vectors or arrays holding the persons, the works, the value after, and the 10 numbers after. Any suggestions?

Comment: "Any suggestions?" - go ahead and do it, and if you have any issues with it, you can post an [mcve] here for your issue, and describe clearly what the problem is. Please read the [help] about the types of questions you can ask here; it has to be specific - "Any suggestions?" is not a valid question here.

Answer (score 2):

[Bad idea](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/147196-moving-away-from-parallel-arrays/).

Make a custom `class` to hold all of the relevant data for your data type. Then create a `new ArrayList<MyClass>()`, or `new HashMap<MyClass>()` if appropriate, to hold all of them.

**See also:**

- [ANTI-PATTERN, PARALLEL COLLECTIONS](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/06/03/anti-pattern-parallel-collections/) by Jon Skeet